# How can I get iball usb tv tuner card to work?

Tags: drivers, usb, tv-tuner

I have an iball USB TV tuner card which only has Windows drivers. I could not get it to run on Ubuntu 13.04.

When I run `lsusb`, I get the following:

```
drdanand@drdanand-HP-Pavilion-g4-Notebook-PC:~$ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 1b80:a418 Afatech 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 148f:2000 Ralink Technology, Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 04f2:b2f4 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
drdanand@drdanand-HP-Pavilion-g4-Notebook-PC:~$
```

My device is the one that reads Afatech.

What do I do? Are there any properitary drivers? Please help.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://askubuntu.com/questions/348740/iball-clarotv-model-t18-usb-tv-fm-tuner-stick-on-ubuntu-13-04

Answer (score 0):

If you found answer Please let me know,
My question : [iBall clarotv model T18 USB TV/FM tuner stick on Ubuntu 13.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/348740/iball-clarotv-model-t18-usb-tv-fm-tuner-stick-on-ubuntu-13-04)

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to add this vid and pid in driver cx231x:

```
sudo modprobe cx231xx
echo "1b80 a418" > /sys/bus/usb/drivers/cx231xx/new_id
```

then see `dmesg` and also `/dev/videoX` abd `/dev/vbi`, open VLC player, capture video, select video node and you can able to watch TV.